# MySQL groupwise query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to calculate the CURRENT location of a person based on a schedule items table (schedules).

The basic premise is, you can schedule a person to be in an office for a certain period of time (let's say start_date=2015-10-01, end_date=2015-12-31). That is a schedule item. It has a 1toM relationship with a location - that's no problem, I have that part sorted.

However, whilst they're scheduled to be in that office, they may also be scheduled to attend an offsite/client office. So there will be another schedule entry for, say, start_date=2015-12-03, end_date=2015-12=04.

Here's the table structure.

```
Person table
----------------------------------------------
|person_id |person_name  |person_email       |
----------------------------------------------
|1         |John         |john@example.org   |
|2         |Jane         |jane@example.org   |
----------------------------------------------

Schedule table
--------------------------------------------------------------
|schedule_id |person_id |location_id |start_date |end_date   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|1           |1         |1           |2015-10-01 |2015-12-31 |
|2           |2         |2           |2015-10-15 |2016-01-15 |
|3           |1         |5           |2015-12-03 |2015-12-10 |
|4           |2         |7           |2015-12-04 |2015-12-12 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I'm querying a single record, I'm easily able to calculate where the person currently is. It's not so complex.

```
SELECT * FROM schedules
WHERE person_id = 1 AND start_date <= CURDATE() AND end_date >= CURDATE
ORDER BY end_date ASC, start_date DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

However, when I need to generate a list of all people with their current schedule item, I'm running into issues. I had initially thought of just using a GROUP BY statement in the query, but that will only ever return the earliest schedule item that matches the query.

The problem therein, is that there are MULTIPLE schedule items that will match the query (this is part of the domain logic). However, I will always select the SHORTEST current stint as their CURRENT location.

I've used a groupwise query in the past to calculate the status of a person's employment based on the most recent status entry. However, because the schedule item has some slightly more complex logic in and around it (it has future scheduled items in it) I'm really just talking myself in circles as to the best approach.

Comment: everything you say under that last blue block could be "I want my input to be" and this is the output table I want. We know you have tried hard ... you don't need to convince us of that. But it just muddies it all up :P

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow if no one answers. But please document what you want the Output to look like

Answer (score 2):

You want to select all records with a starting date before and an end date after the current date. You can get one person multiple times. From that person you want to select the occurrence with the earliest end date. That means you have to order those record by end date and number them within the person group. Try this:

```
select * from (
    select a.scheduled_id
    , a.person_id
    , a.location_id
    , a.start_date
    , a.end_date
    , row_number() over (partition by a.person_id order by a.end_date) as rn
    from schedules a
    where getdate() between a.start_date and a.end_date
    ) tab
where rn=1
```

I added this afterwards because I realized that the row_number function is not available in MySQL. So this is the MySQL version. A bit more complicated but it should work:

```
select * from (
    select @row_num := if(@prev_value=a.person_id,@row_num+1,1) as rn
    , a.scheduled_id
    , a.person_id
    , a.location_id
    , a.start_date
    , a.end_date
    , @prev_value := a.person_id as asgmnt
    from schedules a,
        (select @row_num:=1) x,
        (select @prev_value:=0) y
    where a.start_date<=curdate() and a.end_date>=curdate()
    order by a.person_id, a.end_date
    ) tab
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

A method using a sub query with substring_index. This gets all the schedule ids ordered by the length of time between the end and start dates, then uses SUBSTRING_INDEX to just get the first one. Then joins this against schedules to get the rest of the details.

```
SELECT *
FROM schedules
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT person_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(schedule_id ORDER BY DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)), ',', 1) AS best_schedule_id
    FROM schedules
    WHERE person_id = 1 
    AND start_date <= CURDATE() AND end_date >= CURDATE
    GROUP BY person_id
) sub0
ON schedules.schedule_id = sub0.best_schedule_id
AND schedules.person_id = sub0.person_id
```

Note, I have also returned the person id from the sub query. Not strictly necessary as the query is at the moment, but put it in place so if you start to want to bring back multiple people it will need little change.

Answer (score 0):

I took some motivation from what you gave me and simply decided to do another subquery on the result set, prior to doing a GROUP BY on the output.

```
SELECT s.schedule_id, s.person_id, s.location_id FROM (
    SELECT * FROM schedules
    WHERE person_id = 1 AND start_date <= CURDATE() AND end_date >= CURDATE
    ORDER BY end_date ASC, start_date DESC
) AS s GROUP BY s.person_id
```

This appears to have given me the result set that I was after, unless anybody can think of a reason this would fail?

Comment: That might work, but might not. You are grouping by the s.person_id but also returning s.schedule_id and s.location_id. For person_id 1 there are 2 schedule ids and 2 location ids. Which one is returned is not defined. MySQL could return any of them, and indeed which one it returns could change in future versions of SQL or using different storage engine.